# pass name of member of PARENT class as template argument

Tags: c++, templates

How to pass name of parent's member into template argument?

It is hard to explain, so I will show short code instead.

**Example**

This code has A derived from Mother.  I want to pass name of Mother's field into template of B.

It doesn't compile.  I have marked the line that error occurs.

```
class Mother{
public:
    int motherField=3;   
};

class A: public Mother { 
public:
    int childField=4; 
}; //note: not virtual inherit

template <class T, int T::*a>
class B{ }; 

int main() { 
    B<A,&A::motherField> b;
    //^ could not convert template argument '&Mother::motherField' to 'int A::*'
}
```

If I change from "motherField" to "childField", it can compile.

It looks like the compiler thinks that Mother::motherField is very different from A::motherField

### **Question**

I want to pass the member of parent, is there anyway to make it compile?

### **Motivation**

B is a special hashMap.  Let's name it AMap.

AMap demand that the keys (A) has to dedicate a field (might be int, "motherField" / "childField" in the example) for it, to cache some index.

```
AMap<A,&A::dedicatedField1> b1;  //I omit the value part for simplicity.
AMap<A,&A::dedicatedField2> b2;
A a1;
b1.cache(a1); //b1 read&write a1.dedicatedField1
b2.cache(a1); //b2 read&write a1.dedicatedField2
```

This creates a lot of performance benefit.

```
b1.get(a1);//b1 just read a1.dedicatedField1, then it know where a1 is stored
```

For convenience, I provide a default dedicatedField in Mother of A, so sometimes I can plug Mother::defaultDedicatedField to the AMap (B).

As a result A.h don't have to contain a dedicated field, so code is cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers to members have the type of the class that they're actually members of. So even though you write `&A::motherField`, the type isn't `int A::*` but is really `int Mother::*`. The compile error comes from the type mismatch.

You'd have to cast the pointer to member to the type you want:

```
B<A, static_cast<int A::*>(&A::motherField)> b;
```

But that doesn't work on either gcc or clang (don't understand why yet), so it may be best to provide a 3rd defaulted type parameter in `B` instead. You would use that last type to specify a derived class if necessary - like here:

```
template <class C, int C::*a, class T=C> class B { }; 

B<Mother, &A::motherField, A> b;
```

Comment: Thank! I tried to compile your code, but it is still error (different one).  I have edited the end my question to show the web-link of codes & some error log.  (Feel free to modify it again.)

Comment: @javaLover Updated. Also, don't put that sort of thing into your questions. I edited it out.

Comment: "But that doesn't work on either gcc or clang (don't understand why yet)" You cannot use an arbitrary expression as a non-type template argument. If it's a pointer-to-member, the actual argument must be of the form `&class::member`, and nothing else.

Comment: @n.m. Where is that specified?

Comment: @Barry 14.3.2 Template non-type arguments.

Comment: @n.m. What in there prohibits this? `static_cast<int A::*>(&A::motherField)` is a converted constant expression of the type of the template parameter (`int A::*`).

Comment: @Barry Read carefully, converted constant expressions are only allowed for integral and enumeration non-type parameters. Pointer to member is neither.

Comment: @n.m. Where do you see that? [I don't](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#1).

Comment: @Barry In my local copy of N4140. I believe this may have changed in the recent draft but these changes are not standard yet.

Comment: @Barry It looks like N4140 is the last version with this wording, but the compilers stick to it. The relevant proposal is [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4198.html).